# Firebase Query not Executing Properly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to execute a Firebase query and it doesn't seem to be working properly. I am trying to access the name of a School I have in the Firebase Database. The database looks like this:

```
Schools {

    Random School Name {

        schoolLocation: Random Location
        uid: random UUID

    }
}
```

If I use the following code to get the info of the "Random School Name", I get a snapshot of null:

```
databaseReference.child("Schools").queryEqualToValue("Random School Name").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

    }) { (error: NSError) in

        self.displayError("Search Failed", message: "We couldn't search for that - \(error.code): \(error.localizedDescription)")

}
```

If I use this line of code, however, the query gives me the name of the school back, as I would expect. I want to be able to track if there is an error using `observeSingleEventOfType`:

```
let query = databaseReference.child("Schools").queryEqualToValue("Florida Institute of Technology")

print(query)
```

**Why isn't this working?**

Comment: Whats your Q exactly..?And post your JSON

Comment: How can I get the observeSingleEventOfType block to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're querying by priority here, which will only work if your schools have a priority (highly unlikely).

If that is indeed the problem, solve it by being explicit about the ordering: `queryOrderedByKey()`. Then also be sure to **loop** over the children in the result, since a query will return a list, even if there's only one result:

```
databaseReference
    .child("Schools")
    .queryOrderedByKey()
    .queryEqualToValue("Random School Name")
    .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
            print(snapshot)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Dan you should try this query for retrieving specific data

```
self. databaseReference.queryOrderedByChild("Schools").queryEqualToValue("Random School Name").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)


        })
```

This query returns the random school name for the key schools