# How to filter Firebase data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically, I have a structure called, topics which contains `Title`, `Description` and a `Published` flag (see screenshot below for clarification ).

[image: Topics object in Firebase Database]

In the application, I want to filter the data and only show the topics that have `published = true`.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(FIREBASE_URL).child("topics")
        self.ref?.queryEqualToValue("published")
        self.ref?.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            //...Handle Snapshot here
        })
```

But this is not working. How should I approach this? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have a few small mistakes in there. Overall nothing too bad, but combined they'll never work:

1. calling any of the `query...` methods returns a new object
2. you need to `orderByChild()` before you can filter on its value
3. you need to loop over the results

Combining these:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(FIREBASE_URL).child("topics")
let query = ref.queryOrderedByChild("published").queryEqualToValue(true)
query.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        print(childSnapshot)
    }
})
```

We get this question regularly. For example, this from yesterday looks very similar: [Firebase Query not Executing Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381176/firebase-query-not-executing-properly/39382015#39382015). Since my explanation varies with every answer, I recommend browsing a bit to read my [relevant answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bswift%5d%5bfirebase-database%5d%20loop%20children) until it clicks.

Comment: That was it! Thanks again for the help Frank!

Comment: Is it still possible if the data were nested one more level deep. For example, if under "published" there were a list of keys with true/false values. And you wanted to filter by `/published/key1 = true` This is the problem I'm running into.

Comment: I tried this but I receive all the child values, not just the only ones passing the query criteria. I'm using the .childAdded and the queryStarting(at:). Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Point # 1 is very important. Need to declare variable to store the query and observe the data from that query for correct result.

1. calling any of the query... methods returns a new object

Comment: Is it possible to fetch records same as like we use ? I mean all the record which title starts from "s".

Comment: Yes, that is possible with `queryStarting(atValue:).queryEnding(atValue:)`. See for example the snippet in the **question** here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132981/querying-firebase-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

```
self.ref = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL(FIREBASE_URL).child("topics").
    queryOrderedByChild("published").queryEqualToValue(true)
    .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    for childSnapshot in snapshot.children {
        print(snapshot)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

By using this function you can check any data that exist or not.

```
func checkUserExsistance(_ firURL : String ,_ childNode : String,_ value : String,_ ChildKey : String, completion : @escaping(Bool)->()){

     let DBRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: firURL)

    let newDB =   DBRef.child(childNode).queryOrdered(byChild: ChildKey).queryEqual(toValue: value)
    newDB.observe(.value, with: { (snapPhot) in
        print(snapPhot.value)

    }) { (erooor) in
        print(erooor)
    }
}
```