# Updating username across database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've just started developing an app and having played about with Firebase before I figured it'd be a useful solution to having data stored server side.

I'm at the point where I've got a fully functional login and registration system which takes you to the app, but I've made it so that you require a 'username' before you can get passed the 'further registration' page (where the user sets up their profile information).

Currently, I've got a little note telling the user that they will be unable to update their username after setting it - however I don't really like the idea of this although I feel like I have no choice which is why I'm asking.

If I have multiple uses of the username in multiple places, like so:

```
{
    users: {
        id1234: {
            username: "SomeUser123",
            age: 20
        }
    }
    posts: {
        id445: {
            title: "Some title",
            content: "Some content",
            postedBy: "someUser123"
        }
    }
}
```

How would I go about updating that person's username so that it also updates the post's username field (and likely several other places) in Swift? Or would the best option be to not allow a user to update their name? Which would be a shame.

Comment: One thing I did think of was to have some kind of JOIN but I don't think you can do that in Swift/Firebase.. Which is unfortunate.

Comment: I have no experience with FireBase, but why do you not use a ID (UserId)?

Comment: @Arendax as far as I'm aware, you're unable to JOIN in Firebase as it's kind of all like a flat JSON database - that would be a solution to this problem.

Comment: That would help, but why do you not add a UserID? THAT will be the solution. Than you can just link the post to a UserID

Comment: @Arendax because there is no way so send synchronous requests in Firebase, so you're unable to fetch the user ID and then use that user ID to call user information - as far as I'm aware, if anybody were to enlighten me as to how this could be done that would be life saving.

Comment: Create a reference to the nodes and simply update your values

Comment: @EmilDavid that's sort of what i mean

Comment: @EmilDavid Could you explain what you mean? Preferably in pseudo code or Swift.

Comment: @Jarkerwastaken I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two Methods come to mind

**1. Easy Route**

If you're certain that you'll only be using `username` in those two places, then I'd just create references to them and simply update their value. This method is easy but obviously not scalable.

```
let userReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/id1234")

userReference.updateChildValues([
"values": [
    "sample0",
    "sample1"
    ]
])
```

For the posts one, you'd want to filter first by `postedBy` before updating the value

**2. Multi-path Route**

This is the most scalable option and I'd recommend you reading this [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) about it.

Comment: Just a follow up question to this - When updating the 'posts' object and I'm looking through trying to find the User ID (the postedBy), is there a way to search though _all_ posts? Or do I have to provide a specific post ID in the `.child("posts/id1234") ? You've been a super help.

Comment: No its fine buddy. Glad to help. So when you create a reference to the posts like `let postReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")`, `postReference` actually points to the top of the `post` head. If you actually print the snapshot returned, this will return all of the posts. Now you don't want to do this so instead you point to the head but tell Firebase to filter this data by `postedBy`. Then all you have to do is change the value inside `postedBy`. [Frank](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39647861/4962554) does a great job at explaining this.

Comment: Or as you filter the data, you'd have to filter it by the user's old username since that's what Firebase would have. Then after retrieving this info, you can go ahead and change it to the new username.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll test all of this out later on tonight and will tick your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `updateChildValues` for that.

```
let uniqueId = "id1234" //In your case
let newName = "NewUserName"

let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uniqueId)
ref.updateChildValues(["username":newName])
```

Or you can also use `setValue` for single field update

```
ref.setValue(["username":newName])
```

Comment: Are you having old username value? If Yes then you can get userid `(id1234)` from it and then update the username from it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest way is to store everything using the Firebase uid, but maintain a separate table of displayName for each uid, and then use the uid for the data layer, and displayName for the presentation layer.

This way, you only have to maintain the displayName in one place.