# What is the best way to do a IN query in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Since firebase database doesn't support querying from arrays in `equalTo` how can I do the following query in firebase ?

```
{
  'keyname': 'value1'
},
{
 'keyname': 'value2'
},
{
 'keyname': 'value3'
}
```

How can I retrieve all objects containing value1 and value2 ? Do I make use of the forEach loop or is there another approach to getting the values back.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for a query for all nodes that contain value1 *or* value2. You platform wasn't indicated so I will address it at a high level.

Solution 1 Query all nodes for value1, then query again for all nodes with value2

Solution 2 Query nodes startingAt("value1").endingAt("value2")

Solution 3 Add a structure to keep a reference to those nodes matching both criteria

```
items
  node_0
    keyname: value1
  node_8
    keyname: value2

value1_value2
   node_0: true
   node_8: true
```

Solution 4 Determine a commonality between the values. For example. Say value1 was Apple and value2 was Pear. Both being Fruits and you know your user will want all fruits so query for typeOf is Fruit. You can expand that further by adding grownOn: Tree. Then you can query for all items that are grownOn a tree. You could even add a compound predicate type_grown: Fruit_Tree and then you could query for all fruits that are grown on trees as opposed to all nuts that are grown on trees.

```
{
  keyname: "Apple"
  typeOf: "Fruit"
}
  keyname: "Pear"
  typeOf: "Fruit"
}
```

Solution 5
Load in the entire node and filter in code (this is a fine way to do it depending on the size of the dataset).

Solution 6
Query all nodes that start with the word *value* and reject all of those that are not value1 or value 2. In Swift it would be

```
let nameQuery = usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "keyname")
                        .queryStarting(atValue: "value")
                        .queryEnding(  atValue: "value\u{f8ff}")
```

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132981/querying-firebase-efficiently/45174762#45174762) for more info on that one.