# Retrieving and filtering data in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to filter some user data from firebase by usernames in swift 5, below is my code:

```
func getUsersWithUserName(givenUserName: String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ isSuccess: Bool) -> Void) {
        print("Enter getUsersWithUserName")
        print(givenUserName)
        let usersRef = dbRef.child("users")
        usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userName").queryEqual(toValue: givenUserName, childKey: "userName").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            print("nakul")
            print(snapshot)
            for child in snapshot.children {
                print(child)
                let key = snapshot.key
                print(key)
            }
        })

        print("Exit getUsersWithUserName")

    }
```

Below is my firebase `user` node structure:

[image]

I have read the below answers already :

[How to filter Firebase data in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647742/how-to-filter-firebase-data-in-swift)

[querying firebase efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132981/querying-firebase-efficiently)

but I am still not getting any results.

My log looks like below:

```
Enter searchBarButtonClicked
Enter getUsersWithUserName
nac
Exit getUsersWithUserName
```

I am not really sure what I am missing here.

Comment: silly question - you are testing with username "nac", printing  "naku1" and the example shown is "hello2" ... do you actually have the username you're looking for in the database?

Comment: yes I do, I have a couple of users and with what I am searching. This was just a structure example.

Comment: what do you get if you strip out parts of the query?  remove the ordering, or keep it, and remove the selection part?  It looks like it should work, so if it was me, I would be trying to find the smallest code block that works, and then build it up from there.  good luck

Comment: I did try that, it did not work either. How ever if I just pull the data without any query (order/equal), I get the data.

Comment: Wait. why are you doing this `, childKey: "userName").` when you're already querying by that field? `queryOrdered(byChild: "userName")`? It should just be `usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "userName").queryEqual(toValue: givenUserName).observe...`

Comment: I tried without it, and it was the same. I realized the error was the permission. I was only permitting the user with user-ID to access the node, where as for this query I was supposed to let all users access this data.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, hope this will solve your issue:

```
let query: DatabaseQuery = dbRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "userName").queryEqual(toValue: givenUserName)
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    //Your code here
}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Please comment if you have any questions.

Happy to help!

Comment: So I used your advice to debug. I got the error `Permission denied`. Now that is weird cause I have `"users" : {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    },` while I am writing the app, is this cause I am accessing all nodes with one user, I am confused.

Comment: Can you relogin and try this? which way of auth you are using?

Comment: login back in to the app? Which way of auth meaning?

Comment: yes can you logout and login again?...test after that if this is working

Comment: Nope not working. I created sign in with email and password. nothing fancy.

Comment: let me try removing the `$user_id`. That may be it.

Comment: The error is related to auth. That's why you are not able to access the database.

Comment: the `$user_id` was it, now I am getting `Snap (users) <null>`. Something better than nothing. Thanks a ton. Take my upvote for helping me debug.

Comment: No the issue is still not resolved, I am getting null as my snap. But I did upvote you cause it lead to a path where I am able to start more debugging.

Comment: If you can show me your final query and database result that you are expecting, may be I will be able to help