# Retrieve Data from Firebase using where Query in Swift 4

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

[image]

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "user")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

    if !snapshot.exists() { return }

    print(snapshot) // Its print all values including Snap (User)

    print(snapshot.value!)

    let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "full_name").value
    print(username!)

})
```

Comment: i want to show the video id where videoid = "12345". How to do it in swift 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a query:

```
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "videoid").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#queryorderedbychild

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but it is showing |
[Firebase/Database][I-RDB034028] Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "VideoID" at /Messages to your security rules for better performance

Comment: this is a warning not an error, it is related to firebase database rules

Comment: here check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: Okay.understood. but the matter is in my database there is total 10 values of videoID. out of 5 values r "12345" and rest of 5 are "67890". i want to show the video id which is "12345". and using this query it is only showing 1. please help.

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee make sure all 5 are `videoID` with capital "I" and "D"

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee remove `observeSingleEvent`(since it reads data once) and write `observe` and it will work, see here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: Sir, all the fields are same videoID.

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee okay see my last comment and the link above

Comment: sir i am using this
let abc  = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryStarting(atValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
       })
        
        print(abc)

Comment: sir please reply.

Comment: how are you retrieving?

Comment: Sir, i have written a function.
func retrieveData() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Messages")

           let abc  = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            
        })
        
        print(abc)
    }

Comment: what is `print(abc)` giving you?

Comment: i just want to show the number of fields (videoID) that's starting with "12345". there are five field that starting with "12345"

Comment: that are starting or equal to 12345(because you said equal before..)? If starting then use `queryStarting(atValue:)` https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DatabaseQuery#querystartingatvalue

Comment: that means let abc  = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryStarting(atValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in. this can be possible?

Comment: Peter Haddad Sir can i post the screenshot of database here?

Comment: sir i can't enter the chat room. You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here. it is showing this

Comment: i can't comment there but my reputation is 21 now

Comment: sir are you there?

Comment: try `.queryStarting(atValue: "123").`

Comment: i have used this thing that you mention in chat room. but still it is not showing. let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Messages")
        let abc = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryStarting(atValue: "1").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            
        })
        print(abc)

Comment: sir i have post the screenshot of the database. in the question link. please see

Comment: please see the screenshot

Comment: abhishekblueberrywebs@gmail.com

Comment: Sir are you busy?

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647742/how-to-filter-firebase-data-in-swift

Comment: Following it sir

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: I have done it sir. tell me one thing what is "observe" meaning in the following line. is it a callback? if yes then why we iterate the children inside the callback? 


 let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee observe is an event to read data from the database. You iterate inside of it to access the children of the snapshot that you have. It is explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Sir, i have a question. i want to bind the filter data on a tableview in swift. without using reload tableView manually. 
in android FirebaseListAdapter is responsible for binding as well as reloading.

Comment: sir can you tell me how to append the filter data on an array. Here is my code 
 var childrenList = DatabaseList let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Messages") let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "VideoID").queryEqual(toValue: "12345").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in for childSnapshot in snapshot.children{ print(childSnapshot) self.childrenList.append(snapshot) } }) DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee it is better if you ask it in another question, so me or someone else can help you