# How to do sql like query in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can i query firebase if my query looks like this:

```
Select * from table where employment="teacher" or employment="programmer"
```

Comment: And Why you want to do it?  Firebase has no table (SQL structure) so you can't DO THAT

Comment: I want to fetch a child called employment that has value of either teacher or programmer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39647742/how-to-filter-firebase-data-in-swift

Comment: I know about orderedByChild and queryEqualToValue but queryEqualToValue takes one argument. What should i do in case of or.

Comment: Fetch employment all records and manually filter using swift inbuilt methods. Firebase is too fast you will get instant results don't worry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no like query in firebase realtime database. The following queries are the ones that you can use:

```
Method              Usage
queryOrderedByKey   Order results by child keys.
queryOrderedByValue Order results by child values.
queryOrderedByChild Order results by the value of a specified child key or nested child path.
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sort_data

To solve your problem, you can change your database to the following:

```
users
 pushId
    name       : peter
    employment : programmer
    group      : teachProg
 pushId
    name       : john
    employment : teacher
    group      : teachProg
```

And then use `queryOrderByChild("group").queryEqualToValue("teachProg")` and you will be able to retrieve all users that are programmers or teachers

Answer (score 0):

Firebase database is graph based database which focused on finding optimum path for solution. It doesn't work like sql and supports queries like sql.
Although you can perform various operations like queryOrderedByKey, queryOrderedByValue, queryOrderedByChild etc.

For a reference project using firebase database:
https://github.com/rheyansh/RFirebaseMessaging

For more operations:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data